# Will `not` media query save resources when importing css?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Current I have the following set in the css:

```css
<style>
        @import url("default.css") screen;
        @import url("light.css") screen and (prefers-color-scheme: light);
</style>
```

I want the `default.css` be loaded when 
i) user is in dark mode;
ii) user did not specify any colour theme preferences; or 
iii) user is visiting with a browser that does not support `prefers-colour-scheme` query. 
should I then change the first import rule to `@import url("default.css") screen not (prefers-color-scheme: light);` to save resources, and **will this actually save resources**?

Appreciate for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not it will save resources is browser dependent.

From what I have observed, the media query is evaluated at runtime *after* actually importing the file. You can easily check in the network tabs of the debugging tools if the file is being downloaded or not. This has the most impacts client-side.

**opinionated:**
For the content of the files, you should make your `default.css` agnostic of the colouring scheme (more about common stuff) and have a `light.css` with only changes that apply, and then have another `dark.css` for the "non-light" theme.

The less you override rules, the better (for your own sake).
Although, unless you have millions of rules, the impact of overriding a rule or adding more rules is close to negligible and is/should be optimized by the browser.

Comment: It seems like that when the browser (Safari as example) has light theme set, the browser would load the `light.css` first and after even resources are loaded, download the `dark.css`.

Comment: For your opinion on css, currently I have a `main.css` which defines all colours in variables and use media query to change colour values of variables. the `default.css` and the `light.css` is for JS-formated text only (e.g. highlight code etc.).